# Doesnot get the values when components are different module - NGRX store angular

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

In angular application i have integrated the ngrx/store for state management.
I have 2 modules A & B. First of all I have navigating the Module A to Module using router that time I had dispatching the value in store.

In Module B I got the dispatched value from store. After that navigating Module B to Module A that time also I had dispatched the different values in store but after navigating the dispatched values has changed. Actually after coming Module A its taking the previous state value.

I need help regarding this issue, thank you.

```
Module.A.component.ts;
----------------------
public navigateB() {
 this.store.dispatch(
            setUserStatus({
              existingUser: false
            })
          );
this.router.navigateByUrl('module-b');
}

Module.B.component.ts;
----------------------
public navigateA() {
 this.store.dispatch(
            setUserStatus({
              existingUser: true
            })
          );
this.router.navigateByUrl('module-a');
}

Actual output :
`this.store
      .select((store) => store.userStatus)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res); 
      });`

`userStatus:{ existingUser: false }`

Expected output: 
`userStatus:{ existingUser: true}`
```